# alternative to registering with username and password

Tags: php, mysql

This is what I want to know. I have a site that has a few pages and each page has products that if a user is not logged in does not show prices but when they are logged in they can see the prices... it all works well but I am having trouble with implementing a better password hashing verification/security system than the old md5 system. why I need users to log in is first of all to eliminate nosey competitors snooping around my site for prices (I think having to register and such will put them off as they might think they will be caught out or be identified as competitor), secondly by registering and logging in the users who are really interested will see the prices and should they really like my price they will then request an official quote, where as if they see prices and don't like my price they will not send me unnecessary quotation requests (just to cut down on number of wasted quotations I must sit and type).

so is it possible to instead of asking for username and password (users tend to reuse these details across various sites)? I rather ask for maybe a name and a color as (username and password) so should my database be hacked and details stolen nothing of importance will be displayed (no usernames and passwords linked to bank accounts or such will be stolen as it will only have colors and names)? just a thought. please tell me if it is a stupid idea or if it will work for my application?

so basically registration/login is purely just to eliminate snooping and non-interested buyers. it will not move past that use.

looking forward to hearing your answers and advice. 
P.S be gentle as I am noob of all noobs.

-----EDIT-----

oh here is my registration page details

```
<!-- header goes here -->
<?php include_once("head.php");?>

<?php
require('db.php');

// should add better validation of form submission
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT into users (username, password, email, trn_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['username'], $hash, $_POST['email'], date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

    $result = $stmt->execute();

    if($result){
            echo "<div class='content_landing'><div class='form'><h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><p>Click here to <a href='login_page.php'>Login</a></p></div></div>";
        }
    }else{
?><!-- header ends here -->
<!-- ****************************************** -->
<!-- enquiry / newsletter / login / register goes here -->
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- Main page content goes here -->
<div class="content_landing">
<p><div class="form">
<h1>Registration</h1>
<form name="registration" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required /><br>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required /><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
</div></p>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Ends here -->
<!-- ****************************************** -->
<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- *Footer goes here -->
<?php include_once("footer.php");?>
<!-- Footer ends here -->
```

this is my code once i added your snippets in and removed `if($result):`?>`the`"`"` between the : ?> if results and now the process seem to register. but now you said i must add verify_hash to login page is there any way you could help me

here is my login page details

```
    <?php
    require('db.php');
    // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){

        $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']); // removes backslashes
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); //escapes special characters in a string
        $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);

    //Checking is user existing in the database or not
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: shows.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
            }else{
                echo "<div class='form'><h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
                }
    }else{ ?>
<div class="form">
<h2>Log In to view Prices and Specials</h2>
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required /><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required /><br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<p>Not registered yet? <a href='registration.php'>Register Here</a></p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You don't need to implement password hashing, it's [included in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Using the built in password hash/verify functions, and changing to prepared/parameterized queries will simplify/clean up your code a lot. Asking for colors or solutions like that sounds like it will just confuse users. You could simply add social login (as an addition), it will remove most of the hassle of signing up from the user - but will of course require you to do some more coding.

Comment: @JimL wow, thanks for the super fast response. the thing is I'm a super noob in php... i would really like to have it convenient for users. but i do not have the skill level to do something like that. is there perchance any reference material or tutorials i could look at?

Comment: For comparison you can see your registration code cleaned up here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/674f6073ce34fb6af1c83676dd554b31a1c3fd4e Do note that if changing to something like this (you should) you will need to update your login code to utilize [$valid = password_verify($password, $hash)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: @JimL that code in sandbox would i replace my code with that one? also if I do that it yellows out my form below that code? maybe it is not closed somewhere?

Comment: Yes it was intended to replace your code. Your original posted code ended with an else though (before the form) so that would have to be added back.

Comment: sorry i have taken so long to respond, when i change my code and add yours in and run the code i get the following: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting '`' in D:\xamp\htdocs\test\registration_page.php on line 47